# Private action methods in swift crashes

Tags: ios, swift

In objective-c I define my action methods in .m file. So they become private(sort of) and other classes (view controllers) can't see them.

In swift I tried to do it. But app crashed with unrecognized selector sent to instance error. Here is the action source object.

```
let rememberSwitch = UISwitch()
rememberSwitch.addTarget(self, action: "rememberMeChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

and here is the action method.

```
private func rememberMeChanged(rememberSwitch: UISwitch) {

}
```

Is there another way to make this method hidden from other classes other than define it as private?